# Citing multiple authors from a collection in BibTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to cite two chapters (each written by a different author) of the same book using BibTeX. I know I can use `@incolllection` or `@inbook` to do that but then I guess I have to put in the details of the collection for both entry. What I'd like instead is to have three separate entries on the bibliography, more or less like this:

> AUTHOR 1. 20XX. "Chapter title" in EDITORS (20XX).
> AUTHOR 2. 20XX. "Another chapter title" in EDITORS (20XX).
> EDITORS. 20XX. *Collection Title*

What I tried to do is two create three BibTeX entries:

```
  @book{editor20xx,
     title = {Collection Title},
     editor = {Editors},
     year = {20xx},
  }

  @incollection{author1,
     title = {Chapter title},
     author = {Author 1},
     editor = {Editors},
  }

  @incollection{author2,
     title = {Chapter title},
     author = {Author 2},
     editor = {Editors},
  }
```

When I do this, though, I get something like this on the author entry (see entry for Friedman):

[image]

I remember seeing a post about how to add an entry for a collection and then just refer back to it in the individual chapter entry but for the life I can't remember where.

Hope you guys can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tags you chose I assume you use indeed BibLaTeX (I am not sure if that would work with plain BibTeX). However, if I am correct, then using the `crossref` field should do the trick:

```
@book{editor20xx,
title = {Collection Title},
editor = {Editors},
year = {20xx},
}
    
@incollection{author1,
title = {Chapter title},
author = {Author 1},
crossref = {editor20xx},
}
    
@incollection{author2,
title = {Chapter title},
author = {Author 2},
crossref = {editor20xx},
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this was what I was looking for!